# Refactoring my coffeescript code to get sum of particular columns values

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

This may be an  noob question , but I am an newbie in coffeescript and javascript , I am trying to figure out how can I refactor the below code to get sum of the values from two columns with different class names and display it in my html page here is the code what i have got so far:

```js
totalItems = ->
  column= $("#websiteTable td[class=website_count]")
  theTotal = 0
  column.each ->
    value = $(this).html()
    theTotal += parseInt(value)
    return
  alert(theTotal)

newItems = ->
  column= $("#websiteTable td[class=new_count]")
  theTotal = 0
  column.each ->
    value = $(this).html()
    theTotal += parseInt(value)
    return
  alert(theTotal)
```

as you can see there is lot of repetitive code how effectively can I  rewrite this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Create a function that takes a jQuery selector as a parameter.

```
calculateTotal = (element, total = 0) ->
    element.each ->
        value = $(@).html()
        total += +value

    total
```

Then you can do:

```
totalItems = calculateTotal $ "#websiteTable td[class=website_count]"
newItems = calculateTotal $ "#websiteTable td[class=new_count]"
```

See the live example below.

```js
var calculateTotal;

calculateTotal = function(element, total) {
  if (total == null) {
    total = 0;
  }
  element.each(function() {
    var value;
    value = $(this).html();
    return total += +value;
  });
  
  return total;
};

$('button').on('click', function(){
 alert(calculateTotal($('ul li')));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
 <li>2</li>
   <li>4</li>
</ul>

<button>Calculate the total</button>
```

Comment: `element.toArray().reduce(...)` might be nice instead of the manual summing through `each`. You could also throw a `map` in if you were so inclined.